# How to mock koa context in a function that returns a function with context parameter

Tags: testing, mocking, jestjs, middleware, koa

I have a file, `myFunction.ts` that defines and exports one function:

```
export function MyFunction() {
    return async (ctx: Koa.Context) => {
        //some work happens in here
    };
}
```

This function gets called in a Koa middleware file and inherits the `ctx` from previous middleware. How does one create a mock `ctx` to test `MyFunction()` in this case?

Answer (score 6):

I use Shopify's library [@shopify/jest-koa-mocks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shopify/jest-koa-mocks). They use Koa's `createContext` under the hood if you want to explore building it yourself.

```
import { createMockContext } from '@shopify/jest-koa-mocks';
import { myFunction } from './myFunction.js';

describe('middleware being tested', () => {

    let ctx;
    let myMiddleware;

    beforeEach(() => {
        ctx = createMockContext();
        ctx.addAnythingYouWant = jest.fn();
        myMiddleware = myFunction();
    });

    test('calls function addAnythingYouWant', async () => {
        await myMiddleware(ctx);
        expect(ctx.addAnythingYouWant).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
});
```